# i386-elf-gcc out put strange assembler command about "static a = 0"

Tags: c, gcc, i386

i am write a mini os. And when i write this code to show time clock, its goes wrong

```
  7 void timer_callback(pt_regs *regs)
  8 {
  9     static uint32_t tick = 0;
 10     printf("Tick: %dtimes\n", tick);
 11     tick++;
 12 }
```

tick is initialise not with 0, but 1818389861. but if tick init with 0x01 or anything else zero, it's ok!!!

so i wirte a simple c file then objdump:

```
staic.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
extern void printf(char *, int);

int main(){
   0:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   4:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   7:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   a:   55                      push   %ebp
   b:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   d:   51                      push   %ecx
   e:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
    static int a = 1;
    printf("%d\n", a);
  11:   a1 00 00 00 00          mov    0x0,%eax
  16:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  19:   50                      push   %eax
  1a:   68 00 00 00 00          push   $0x0
  1f:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   20 <main+0x20>
  24:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
    return 0;
  27:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  2c:   8b 4d fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
  2f:   c9                      leave
  30:   8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
  33:   c3                      ret
```

so strange, no memory used!!!

Update: let me say it clearly

1. the second static.c is an experiment, it was thought it show no memory used, but i was wrong, `mov 0x0 %eab` is. i confuse 0x0 and $0x0 /..\
2. my origin problem is why tick not succeed init with 0.(but can init with 1 or anyelsenumber).
3. i look up it again use gdb, ok, it do use memory like `mov

   eax,ds:0x106010`,but the real strong thing is the memory `x 0x106010` is not 0,but it should be, just as i said, if i let `tick = 1 or anythingelse`, memory do init as i want, that is the strange thing!
4. the tool: gdb ,objdump return different asm(different means,not formate),because, just learn os,not good at c, so i let it go,ignore it....

Comment: What is the question here ? You also show some C code, but the disassembly is for something different - what is the connection ? Where is the strange assembly you refer to ?

Comment: If tick isn't printing as zero when you first call timer_callback, then you must have undefined behaviour somewhere else in your code. In your second example with `a` no memory used because the compiler has optimised it away, it doesn't need to be static because you only print the value once then quit.

Comment: The instruction at 11: is a mov from address 0x0 to %eax. The reason the address is 0x0 is because this is an object file and the relocations that the linker does haven't been done. After linking, this will be a proper address from a proper memory location where `a` is stored.

Comment: @Secto Kia no matter what name i gave it,  still not zero. what "undefined behaviour" did you mean?

Comment: Most the rest of your code. You must have some other code that is wrong causing undefined behaviour. A program will just your timer_callback function works and does print "0times". Your probably is not with timer_callback. If you have a mistake somewhere else, you could be unknowingly writting over the top of the memory used tick.

Answer (score 3):

Memory is used, be sure of that; however, you won't find that memory in the `.text` section. Memory for static variables is allocated in either `.bss` (when zero-initialized; or, in case of C++, dynamically initialized) or `.data` (when non-zero initialized) section.

When dumping object files with `objdump` using the `-d` (disassembly) option, it is important to also use the `-r` (relocations) option. Without that, the disassembly you get is deceiving and makes little sense.

In your case, the instruction at addresses `11` and `1f` must have relocations, at address `11`, to the variable `a` and at address `1f`, to the function `printf`. The instruction at address `11` loads the value from your variable `a`, without proper relocations it looks as if it loaded a value from address 0.

As to your original question, the value you get, 1818389861, or 0x6C626D65, is quite remarkable. I would bet that somewhere in your program you have a buffer overrun involving a string containing the subsequence `embl`.

As a side note, I would like to call your attention to the use of correct type specifications in `printf` calls. The type specification `%d` corresponds to the type `int`; on all modern mainstream architectures, `int` and `int32_t` are of the same size. However, that is not guaranteed to always be so. There are special type specifications for use with explicitly-sized types, for example, for an `int32_t` you use `"PRId32"`:

```
uint32_t x;
printf("%"PRId32, x);
```

Comment: Excellent, knowledgable answer. That ASCII sequence is a great catch. But you missed a spot. `1a` also has a relocation. The constant pushed there is the address of the format string.

Comment: @Art, True; I spent too much time musing over instruction at address `27`. Why did the compiler emit so a long instruction here?

Comment: I get `mov $0, %eax` with gcc below -O2, at -O2 I get the more expected `xorl %eax,%eax`. I guess gcc doesn't even bother generating good code for simple constant loads without higher optimization levels. Weird, but not entirely unsurprising.

Comment: Of course, test compiling this at -O2 is pointless since gcc sees that `a` can't be modified and just pushes a constant to the stack

Comment: great answer, i not recagnize `mov 0x0, %eax`, i think it is .. `mov $0x0,%eax`.

but the origin question, if something else overwrite it, why i init it with 1 or anything else 0 will not cause the problem? 

and, thanks for the end, actually `printf` is implement by myself ...

Comment: @petelin, As I said before, zero-initialized data are placed in the `.bss` section, while nonzero-initialized data, in the `.data` section. So, by initializing your variable by something else than 0, you cause it to be placed in a different location which is not affected by the buffer overrun.